# google app engine 17 new warning messages

Tags: google-app-engine

After upgrading our google app engine app from Java 8 to Java 17 with legacy services, we are seeing warning messages in the app engine logs as follows (approx 15 per hour):

```
[pid1-app] Exit 143 app (pid 11): /bin/sh -c exec serve WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml [session:1L5GSXC]
```

Does anyone have any idea what these are or how to correct them?

Comment: I would suggest checking your application logs and error messages to see if there are any issues that could be causing these warnings. Additionally, you may want to reach out to the [Google Cloud Support](https://cloud.google.com/support-hub) team for assistance with troubleshooting these warning messages.